# Scaling Image Hosting With Multiple Servers

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I have an image host which is gaining in popularity and need to start thinking about scaling (it's all currently hosted on a single machine).

I want to host the content on multiple amazon machines in order to be able to scale horizontally.

Can someone give me a basic rundown of the architecture (DB, image files, etc.) and or point me to some resources?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the database is concerned, you probably want to use replication - whereby your 'master' database is replicated (in real time) to several 'slave' databases.  All transactional statements (inserts, updates, deletes, etc.) are executed on the master database, then these are replicated to all of the slave databases in real time.  Then, you can distribute the applications queries (select statements) across all of the slave databases for load balancing.

You may also want to keep copies of files on multiple servers for redundancy.  Tools like rsync are good for this.

Finally, Amazon has cloud load balancers, so that incoming connections can be distributed to multiple servers.